# Célula não mostra todas as informações(.CSV)

Tags: c#, csv

Estou gerando um arquivo .CSV no meu projeto em c#. A maioria das informações saem corretas, porem quando possui uma grande quantidade de numeros, a célula não mostra todos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e o arquivo é gerado assim:

**Chamada da Função de criar**

```
var arquivo = Service.CriarArquivo(paraEnviar, inclusaoRadioButton.Checked, motivo);
```

**Função de criar**

```
public Arquivo CriarArquivo(IDictionary<Cliente, IEnumerable<ContasReceber>> clientes)
{
     Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo();
     var config = GetConfiguracao();
     PreencherCabecalho(arquivo, config);
     PreencherDetalhe(arquivo, config, clientes);
     return arquivo;
}
```

**Preencher Detalhe**

```
arquivo.Detalhe = new List<Detalhe>();
int sequencial = 1;
foreach (var c in clientes)
{
   Detalhe d = new Detalhe();
   var cob = c.Value.First();
   d.DocumentoDoPrincipal = c.Key.Cnpj;
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Key.Telefone) && c.Key.Telefone.Length == 10)
   {
      d.DDD = int.Parse(c.Key.Telefone.Substring(0, 2));
      d.Tel = long.Parse(c.Key.Telefone.Substring(2, 8));
   }
   d.DtVencDivida = cob.DataVencimento.Value;
   arquivo.Detalhe.Add(d);
}
```

**Detalhe:**

```
[Line(Length = 600)]
public class Detalhe
{
   [Column(Length = 20)]
   public string DocumentoDoPrincipal { get; set; }
   [Column(Format = "000")]
   public int DDDDevedor { get; set; }
   [Column(Format = "00000000")]
   public long TelDevedor { get; set; }
   [Column(Format = "dd/MM/yyyy")]
   public DateTime DtVencDivida { get; set; }
}
```

O objetivo é apenas que apareçam todos os caracteres, o tamanho da célula não importa.

Comment: O problema está na configuração das colunas do Excel, mas penso que com ficheiro CSV não consegue alterar isso programaticamente. Se utilizasse os Interops do Excel, aí seria diferente.

Comment: @JoãoMartins então sem modificar na própria planilha, não tem como?

Comment: @BrunoMiqueas abre o teu CSV num editor de texto para verificar se os dados estão corretos. O problema aí é que o Excel não consegue mostrar toda a informação da tua coluna porque ela está muito estreita. Experimenta aumentar o tamanho da coluna. É problema na apresentação dos dados do excel mesmo, não é nos dados.

Comment: Para modificar isso você teria que usar outro formato como o `.xlsx` que possuem metadados e podem guardar informações como largura da coluna X. Um arquivo CSV é apenas um arquivo TXT com um padrão específico.